# Cassandra CQL with jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, cql

I have created a simple table in cassandra using cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5 jar

```
create table test(id text primaty key, starttime timestamp);
```

Now when I fire select query `:: select * from test`  using the following code:

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test");
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at the stmt.executeQuery line
```

however if I use `:: select id from test` , I get correct response and my query runs perfectly.

The problem is to retrieve timestamp column using cassandra jdbc.

Comment: Can you run a query like select column1, column2, column3 from test instead of using select *, which is a very bad practice in general?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra do you use? The jdbc driver doesn't work with 2.x.

Comment: Besides @MikhailStepura's question, afaik the jdbc driver hasn't been updated since last May so I wouldn't go that way.

Comment: Before you go to far down this track, I would recommend seriously considering the datastax java driver (version 2.0). Its in RC (release candidate) and seems quite stable for what I have been using. This is one of the drivers that is likely to be supported for quite some time to come.